# Windows Phone 7 textBox

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working in Windows phone 7, and I am learning the basics in it. I basically have a `textBox` which can get a username in it, and I want it to have a `placeHolder` like `example@abc.com`, and on tapping the textBox, the text should disappear and the it should be empty for input.

How do I setup a placeholder ? And if possible, can you help me with the code for email verification ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the `PhoneTextBox` from the wp7/Silverlight [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) is all you need. :)

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="example@abc.com" />
```

Some [tutorial](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-PhoneTextBox-in-depth).

Comment: There are many bugs in SLTK implementation. Actually u'd have to fix them  manually.

Comment: @Belorus there are a number of bug fixes for this control in the November's release.

Comment: they fixed some and introduced some new. The phonetextbox still has issues. Create textbox with hint, focus it, write text, then delete text by backspace button and type some text again.

Comment: @Belorus I tried what you described above and it seems working fine, what exactly the issue you are talking about?

Comment: 1. The text color should change(become lighter). 2. The hint becomes visible when u remove last symbol but still in focus(u should see hind and cursor)

Comment: @Belorus you are right! I also upvoted the issue you logged in codeplex, hopefully they can get it fixed soon... For now I will see if I can come up with something as a temporary fix... Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Sure. Probably if u need a quick fix - u can take my version and put it to latest SLTK sources and build. It fix this problems.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/77diz64xzue7g1k/PhoneTextBox.cs

Answer (score 2):

Google *windows phone watermark textbox*; you'll find several implementations. Here's [one](https://watermarktextbox.codeplex.com/) off codeplex.

Comment: Not sure why you'd be downvoted, this is a perfectly good solution

Comment: I would downvote this answer because of the "Just google for it"-reference: You could say that for nearly 50% of all questions and the result may vary in a couple of weeks / month when another user takes a look at this thread. But I would also upvote it for the Codeplex-Link as an example. So, just no vote this time from me.